# Pygame event not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This is my code I have for a game I am making and I manage to get the first text written to the screen then it manages to print the events but it won't run the second part of the code. I am assuming that `if event.type == pygame.K_RETURN:`
doesn't work. I am either doing something wrong or it's not working.

```
while True:   
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #print(event)
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print("key pressed")
            if event.type == pygame.K_RETURN:
                print(event)
                print("enter key pressed")
                screen.fill(blue)
                textSurf, textRect = text_objects(t2, smallText)
                textRect.center = ((700),(100))
                screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
                pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `if event.type == pygame.K_RETURN:` should be `if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:`.

The `pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.KEYUP` event types have a `key` attribute that is used to check which key was pressed.

You can find a list of event types and their attributes in the docs:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html